# Create 2 similar-name files with content from 2-line output of a command

Tags: files, io-redirection

I perform `cmd` and it outputs 2 lines of text:

```
$ cmd
foo
bar
```

I need to write these to: `/long/path/x.{load,conf}

Writing to this destination requires superuser privilege, which rules out manually doing:

```
$ echo "foo" > /long/path/x.load
$ echo "bar" > /long/path/x.conf
```

as *"redirection is done before the command (sudo) starts and acquires privilege"*

Given that `foo` and `bar` are themselves placeholders for unwieldy text strings, what's a good way to accomplish this?

I'm actually looking for a solution that causes least head scratching, as this represents a step in a sequence of instructions, and it would be nice to write code that speaks for itself, however I'm always interested in all the possible ways to do something.

Answer (score 2):

Awk's redirection operator comes in handy here. Here are a few variations on this theme.

```
cmd | sudo awk '{print >"/long/path/x." (NR==1 ? "load" : "conf")}'
cmd | sudo x=/long/path/x awk 'NR==1 {print >ENVIRON["x"]".load"}
                               NR==2 {print >ENVIRON["x"]".conf"}'
cmd | sudo awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 {exit} {print >ARGV[NR-1]}' -  /long/path/x.{load,conf}
```

The first one is the shortest and about as straightforward as it gets. Each line is printed to the file name determined by evaluating the expression after the `>` operator. The current line number `NR` is used to calculate the file name. Juxtaposition of expressions is the string concatenation operator in awk.

Answer (score 1):

People usually do this with `tee`:

```
cmd | sudo tee /long/path/x.{load,conf}
```

`tee` writes copies of its input to all of its named output files - and in the same way the redirection occurs before an `exec` so also does the argument generation in brace expansion. So the above should work fine and write to both resulting file names at once and the standard out.

If you would rather not see what `tee` writes on your terminal as it copies the data though, you can redirect standard out to `/dev/null` - `sudo` won't interfere with that redirection.

You should note though that - as written - `tee` will truncate the output files before writing to them. If you wanted to append instead you could just add the `-a`ppend switch and `tee` would copy the input data to the tail of all named output files.

To write each line to separate locations is a little more difficult admittedly. But `sed` offers the `w`rite command. Combine it with its `-e`xpression argument and you can write the whole `sed` script with brace expansion:

```sh
cmd | sudo sed -e'$x;/./w '/long/path/x.{load,conf}$'\n1x'
```

...will `w`rite the first line into the first argument file and the second line into the second. The e`x`changes just balance the script across first and second lines - to prevent `sed` from writing both lines into both files for each line.

I tested it like:

```sh
printf %s\\n 1 2 | 
sed -e'$x;/./w '/tmp/{1,2}$'\n$!x'
```

... and afterwards ran...

```sh
head /tmp/[12]
```

...which printed...

```sh
==> /tmp/1 <==
1
==> /tmp/2 <==
2
```

Comment: This outputs the entire output of `cmd` to each file. OP requires that 1st line of `cmd` output be written to the 1st file, and 2nd line to 2nd file ...

Comment: @Peter.O - you know, I think you're right. Thank you/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want a solution to script the whole thing (from the `cmd` command to the `.load` and `.conf` files settings, but as per setting these file you can still do it using sudo but you indeed need the redirection to be part of the *sudoed* command:

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'foo' > /long/path/x.load"
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'bar' > /long/path/x.conf"
```

Here `sudo` will get higher privilege, then run `sh` shell which, in turn, will interpret the given command and only at that moment the redirection will take place, avoiding any privilege issue.

If by any chance you need to script this, depending on your exact needs this might look as something like that:

```
cmd | {
    read line
    sudo sh -c "echo '$line' > /long/path/x.load"
    read line
    sudo sh -c "echo '$line' > /long/path/x.conf"
}
```

Comment: The OP mentions that `foo` and `bar` are *unwieldy text strings*. – `read -r` will prevent backslash escape, eg. `\t` remains as `\t`. – `IFS= read` will handle whitespace properly. – However, when calling `sh`, backslash escape *is* applied, thereby converting `\t` to a real *tab char*, and `\d` to a `d`, etc: eg. `sh -c "echo 'a\tz'"`